# Two magnets with Iron truncated cone or pyramid. How low inclination can the truncated cone or pyramid be made?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Two magnets with Iron truncated cone or pyramid: Frustrum

**How much low inclination can the truncated cone or pyramid: Frustrum be made,
without non homogeneous lines of magnetic field coming out from the sides ?????????**
[image: Cone_Inclination]

Two magnets with Iron truncated cone and Yoke
[image: Two magnets with Iron truncated cone and Yoke]

[Link_to_Example_1](http://www.kjmagnetics.com/gap.calculator.asp)

Two magnets with Iron truncated pyramid and Yoke
in a different set up.
[image: Two magnets with Iron truncated pyramid and Yoke]

[Link_to_Example_2](http://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/How-can-I-create-a-magnetic-field-that-is-as-homogeneous-as-possible)

Knowing the magnetic flux at the larger base of the truncated cone or Frustrum,
the area of the smaller base will be the one in which you get the
magnetic saturation of the Iron.
But, ... **How much low inclination can the truncated cone or Frustrum be made,
without non homogeneous lines of magnetic field coming out from the sides ?????????**
[image: Cone_Inclination]

Also in the image of Link_to_Example_2 the gray rectangular number 2 is
a block between the iron pieces to keep the distance between the two parts. It must also be a non ferromagnetic material like brass, wood, stainless steel, etc.
**But what's the best material to hold strong compression and not catch magnetic field
drawing it away from the main gap (number 4) ???**

Help please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the trivial edit. I blame the  SE editor toolkit.